# Python - matplotlib, Restore cursor type after trigger zoom/pan

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I created a custom button on a plot.
What I'm looking for is that if this `CustomButton` was clicked, one of the following will happen:

1. If zoom was active, deactivate it, change cursor to regular cursor, and don't show the zoom rect - Currently, my code disables the zoom ability, but the zoom rect is still visible. This means that if I click back on the figure, and then move the mouse, it will not zoom in, but will still draw the zoom rect.
2. If pan was active, deactivate it and change cursor to regular cursor - Currently, my code **does NOT** disable the pan.

In both cases, the disabling is happening only after I mouse click the figure, and not the actual button (which is why I'm having problems in the first place). I want the above to happen as soon as I click the button, and not only after I click the figure.

So to summarize, I want to disable zoom/pan if the `CustomButton` was hit, and make sure that the cursor goes back to it's original state.

here's the code I have which produces the issues I mentioned:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["toolbar"] = "toolmanager"
from matplotlib.backend_tools import ToolToggleBase


def simple_plot(mat):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.plot(np.reshape(mat, [-1, 1]))
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.legend()
    tool_exists = False
    tm = fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager
    tm.add_tool(name="CustomButton", tool=ToolToggleBase)
    fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool(tm.get_tool("CustomButton"), "toolgroup")
    return fig, ax


class NewButton:
    def __init__(self, fig1):
        self.fig = fig1
        self.cid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)
        tm = self.fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager
        self.button = tm.get_tool("CustomButton")

    def onclick(self, event):
        if self.button.toggled:
            # If navigation mode is PAN/ZOOM turn off
            zoom_button = self.fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.get_tool("zoom")
            if zoom_button.toggled:
                self.fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.trigger_tool("zoom")

            pan_button = self.fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.get_tool("pan")
            if pan_button.toggled:
                self.fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.trigger_tool("pan")
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

x = [1, 2, 3]
fig, ax = simple_plot(x)
clicker = NewButton(fig)
plt.show()
```

Thanks,
Alon.